# Selenium visible element not recognized as visible

Tags: dom, selenium, visible

Have a look at the following code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id(":8")
elem.click()
time.sleep(1)

elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country_residence")
print "elem visible ? = " + str(elem.value_of_css_property('visibility'))
Select(elem).select_by_value("DE")
```

The print states that the element is visible a this moment:

```
elem visible ? = visible
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace: 
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/0s/j6874rlj63qccjx38ltmwy880000gn/T/tmppJ09Vu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8791:5)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/0s/j6874rlj63qccjx38ltmwy880000gn/T/tmppJ09Vu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11438:1)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/0s/j6874rlj63qccjx38ltmwy880000gn/T/tmppJ09Vu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:11)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///var/folders/0s/j6874rlj63qccjx38ltmwy880000gn/T/tmppJ09Vu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460:7)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///var/folders/0s/j6874rlj63qccjx38ltmwy880000gn/T/tmppJ09Vu/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402:5)
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Is the behavior consistent? Does increasing `time.sleep()` interval help or change the behavior? Could you share the link to the web-site so that we can reproduce it too? Thanks.

Comment: attach html sample, pls. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Selenium way to check whether an element is visible is to use the `is_displayed()` method. Given what you've described, if you do:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("country_residence")
print elem.is_displayed()
```

you should get `False` as a result. There are multiple reasons an element may be invisible. The `visibility` CSS property is one of them. There's also the `display` property. And then consider that the visibility of the element's parents and grandparents can affect whether it is visible. It could be off-screen, etc.

Checking the element's `visibility` CSS property in isolation is definitely not the way to check whether it can be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium understands that element is visible/invisible not just by 'visibility' property. As it's written for selenium's "is_visible" method:

"Determines if the specified element is visible. An
 element can be rendered invisible by setting the CSS "visibility"
 property to "hidden", or the "display" property to "none", either for the
 element itself or one if its ancestors.  This method will fail if
 the element is not present."

So, answering your question "How is that possible?" - it (element or it's ancestors) can have no property 'visibility', but can have 'display:none' property